# Bootstrap3 drawer menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, slidingdrawer

Has anybody successfully implemented a drawer menu in bootstrap 3 yet? I've had a go with http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/ but cant seem to do it... http://goo.gl/C9ycJb. Or alternatively have you managed to convert the bootstrap standard collapse to collapse sideways in/out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this example on Bootply helps..

http://bootply.com/88026

You need to shrink the browser width to see the collapse side menu.

Comment: Thanks Skelly, that's just what I wanted, apart from items being on the top nav (in desktop) rather than on the side to but its a good starter for 10. cheers

Answer (score 4):

Didn't see this... http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/ didnt know the term "offcanvas".